# Implement Menu item from main to fragment

Tags: java, android, android-menu

Good day to all. On option menu item click I run one method It works fine but if click again list update but the first items of the list does not delate it show twice. Need on click listview refresh and list only show new items.

This is tab layout so I only write some code hear

MainActvity

```
TAZA taza;

    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter ( FragmentManager fm ) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem ( int position ) {


        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                 taza = new TAZA();

                return taza;


        return null;
    }


    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu ( Menu menu ) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected ( MenuItem item ) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.refresh) {

       taza.aa();


        return true;
}
```

this is fragment tab;
TAZA.java

```
 public class TAZA extends Fragment {


public TAZA () {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


ArrayList <NewsItem> newsItemsList;
ListView lvRss;
NewsAdaptor adapter;
Button button;
ProgressDialog pDialog;
@Override
public View onCreateView ( LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                           Bundle savedInstanceState ) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.taza, container, false);
    lvRss = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listtaza);
    newsItemsList = new ArrayList <>();
    RequestQueue queue = MySingleton.getInstance(getActivity().getApplicationContext()).
            getRequestQueue();


    return view;
}



    public void aa(){
    StringRequest stringRequest1 = new StringRequest
        ("https://politepol.com/feed/18863", new Response.Listener <String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse ( String response ) {
                Log.d("asd","aa");
                Document documentgeo = Jsoup.parse(response);
                Elements itemElementsge = documentgeo.getElementsByTag("item");
                for (int i = 0; i < itemElementsge.size(); i++) {
                    Element itemge = itemElementsge.get(i);

                    String s = itemge.child(0).text();
                    Document document1 = Jsoup.parse(s);
                    String img = document1.getElementsByTag("img").first().attr("src");
                    String title = document1.getElementsByTag("img").first().attr("title");
                    String link = document1.getElementsByTag("a").first().attr("href");
                    String dateeee = rem1(itemge.child(3).text());
                    Log.d("zxc",""+link);
                    String datevee = dateeee;
                    SimpleDateFormat spf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss");
                    Date newDate = null;
                    try {
                        newDate = spf.parse(datevee);
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    spf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
                    datevee = spf.format(newDate);

                    NewsItem newsItem = new NewsItem();
                    newsItem.setImagePath(img);
                    newsItem.setDate(datevee);
                    newsItem.setTitle(title);
                    newsItem.setLink(link);
                    newsItem.setDatedisplay("DATE" + "  " + rem(datevee));
                    newsItemsList.add(newsItem);

                }
                adapter = new NewsAdaptor(getContext(), newsItemsList);
                lvRss.setAdapter(adapter);
                lvRss.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick ( AdapterView <?> parent, View view, int position, long id ) {

                        NewsItem currentNews = newsItemsList.get(position);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), Detail.class);
                        intent.putExtra("NEWS", currentNews);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse ( VolleyError error ) {
                aa();
                Log.d("asd","a");
            }
        });
    MySingleton.getInstance(getContext()).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest1);
}
```

newsApapter

```
public class NewsAdaptor extends BaseAdapter {
TextView tvtitle;
RelativeLayout view2;
Context context;

private int color;
private int colorback;
private int textSize;

public NewsAdaptor ( Context context, ArrayList <NewsItem> newsList ) {
    this.context = context;
    this.newsList = newsList;
    this.color = Color.RED;

}

ArrayList <NewsItem> newsList;


@Override
public int getCount () {

    return newsList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem ( int position ) {

    return newsList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId ( int position ) {
    return 0;
}

@SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
@Override
public View getView ( int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent ) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = View.inflate(context, R.layout.newsitemlist_layout, null);

    }
    NewsItem currentNews = newsList.get(position);
    ImageView iv1 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.mainimg);
    tvtitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1id);

    TextView tvdate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pubDateid);

    tvtitle.setText(currentNews.getTitle());
    tvdate.setText(currentNews.getDatedisplay());
    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add `newsItemList.clear()` at start of method. It will not make duplicate data.